# How does the presenter in this video derive this formula?

Tags: notation, information-theory

I am watching this [coursera video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn4vZvOEqB0) on entropy (in the information theory sense of the word). Right around the two minute mark the presenter shows two forms for H(p). The first (after the equals sign) is a definition. But I do not understand how he derives the second form (after the second equals sign). I guess I am not that familiar with the bracket notation [] that he uses to define the "expectation over the surprise." What does it mean for X to be "over" Y? What does that have to do with this notation?

[image]

Comment: BTW you can make youtube link which also [specifies the time, where the video starts playing](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/732/linking-directly-to-a-specific-point-in-time-of-a-youtube-video). The link could look like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn4vZvOEqB0#t=131

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking about the equality
$$E_p\left[\log_2 \frac1{p_x}\right] = -\sum_x p_x\log_2 p_x$$
then it is just the definition of [expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)
and using $\log_2\frac1x=-\log_2x$. (Which, of course, works for logarithms at any base, not just base two.)